# Run PowerAutomate flow from PowerApps without needing to provide service account credentials

Tags: powerapps, connector, power-automate

I have a PowerApp that calls a PowerAutomate workflow. In the workflow I am using the Gmail connector to send an email. I created a service account in gmail and used that. Now anyone that uses the PowerApp is asked to provide those SA credentials. I still don't fully understand the scope of connectors, but is there a way to make like a global connector that all users have so it doesn't require them to know credentials?

Or any other route would be helpful too. We plan to have everyone in the company use this tool at some point and I really don't want every person to have to log in to the connector on first use. Let alone knowing the service account credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issues occurs when you trigger the Flow from PowerApp. It tries to take the context of the user who is clicking the button.

Unfortunately, could not find a way / configuration to break this.

However, there is a workaround I found

- Completed the required action in the actual flow
- At the end, triggered another flow - this second flow is responsible send an email

[image]

### Explanation :

In the root flow which was triggered from the Power App, at the end of this :

I issued a post request from the first workflow  :

**First flow**

[image]

passed the necessary information in the body of this request.

Had configured the second flow to get triggered on the HTTP Request.  The Second flow sent the email - using the service account.

**Second Flow**
[image]

The POST URL gets auto generated when you click on the Save button.

You will have to create the Request Body JSON Schema ( Or you can generate through a sample payload- click on the "Use Sample Payload to generate schema")

[image]

This  second flow can have the email trigger actions.

Comment: Ok, that was where my mind originally went. If I could somehow fire another workflow from the first workflow. Looks like you were able to with an HTTP post. Could you explain the URI briefly and how it calls the original workflow? Thank you

Comment: Also, could I reverse that? Could I have a workflow that fires from the PowerApp button that does an HTTP POST of a SharePoint ID (because the main workflow just needs the ID from the PowerApp anyway) as the service account? That saves reworking the initial flow to just needing to receive the request.

Comment: Yeah you could do that ! ... have the powerapp button a trigger a flow which inturn issues a HTTP request to the second flow... that was my initial suggestion. Added few more screenshots and updated my answer to make it little clearer. let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: 1. Does the SharePoint list item ID come through as a string or does it not matter?
2. Can I see the whole screenshot of the HTTP action?
3. Does the first flow need to send authentication? If so, as the AD service account or the gmail-created service account address that is used for the Gmail connector?

Comment: Does the HTTP trigger of the second flow need to be a GET since the first flow HTTP action is a POST? Or does it need to match as a POST method?

Comment: It seems to have worked!
I would like to better understand the authentication though. When I added the HTTP action and left the authentication alone it worked fine. So is that saying the HTTP POST from the first flow is coming through as my AD service account? Even when my normal user clicks the button on to trigger the first flow the SA sends the HTTP action?